# Gatsby WorkError - Crashing on image processing

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

This is the error I'm getting after I run gatsby develop. This same build worked fine yesterday on my work PC, it is windows and I am currently trying to install on Ubuntu, not sure if that's related because this error doesn't make any sense to me.

```
Processing /home/nolan/Gatsby/Ecom-Doc/src/images/Wheel-Store.jpg failed

Original error:
spawn /home/nolan/Gatsby/Ecom-Doc/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp ENOENT



  WorkerError: Processing /home/nolan/Gatsby/Ecom-Doc/src/images/Wheel-Store.jpg failed
  Original error:
  spawn /home/nolan/Gatsby/Ecom-Doc/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp ENOENT

  - jobs-manager.js:316 exports.enqueueJob
    [Ecom-Doc]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/jobs-manager.js:316:23


not finished run queries - 0.538s
not finished Generating image thumbnails - 0.512s

(sharp:6999): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:06:50.394: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I already found an answer that worked, but I still have no idea what caused this or why this fix works. Anyone with an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

From the repo:

> Turned out in the end to be related to our corporate network. Npm
>   needed the certificate passed to install the package correctly.

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=~/cert.pem yarn
```